# Replacing a String with a python variable in sql query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

so I know that similar questions have been asked before, but the solutions posted do not seem to work for me, unless perhaps I am doing it wrong.

I want to change this:`query1= ("SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE 'asperges'" )`
where the output is  `51962, Asperges`

into something like this:

`asperges= "asperges"
cursor.execute(query1,asperges)
query1= ("SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE '%s'")`

problem: output is all wrong (I'm printing in a for loop on the cursor just for reference), and instead of getting just one match, I'm getting a match on all titles in that table.

what's up?

(because someone will probably tell me to do something like this: 
`query1= ("SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE '%s'" , asperges)`

That query is giving me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For cursor.execute you can give two arguments: first the string with the values to replace ("%s") and the second one is a tuple, so either you can throw this to your cursor (best option!):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE %s",('aspergers',))
```

DO NOT FORGET the comma after 'aspergers'! It converts your data to a tuple.

Or you can set a query and give it to the cursor:

```
query1= "SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE %s"  % (asperges,)
cursor.execute(query1)
```

CHECK THE COMMA again.

Comment: thank you! What I ended up doing was this: 
cursor.execute("SELECT anthologyID, title FROM newschema.item WHERE title LIKE %s"  ,(asperges,))
what does replacing the percent with the comma do, 
also, a bit of a related question: 
how would I be able re-create something like %asperges% where I want to match other characters after the last s in 'asperges' in the LIKE
thank you

Comment: If you want to write the '%' character, just double it '%%'. e.g.:
"(...) WHERE title like '%%%s%%'"